# Using JWT in Azure AD implicit flow to login to Azure SQL

Tags: authentication, azure-sql-database, jwt

I have a SPA that logs users in with AAD and passes the JWT to a Web Api when making HTTP calls.  I am trying to use this token that I capture in the Web Api to authenticate to Azure SQL using **SqlConnection.AccessToken** .

I am constantly getting "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'".

I registered the app in AAD and am using the app id when requesting the token

Answer (score 0):

This is not doable because a JWT can only have a single Audience.  In order for this to work, an additional Audience Id would be required for Azure SQL.